# How to convert a case Class to Json-LD in Scala?

Tags: java, json, scala, semantic-web, json-ld

Currently I have a case class like

```
case class A(a:String, b:String, c:C,d:D)
case class C(e:String,f:String)
case class D(g:String,h:String)
```

When I try to make a convert a object A to Json , it is successfully done using any normal Json parser like lift-json.

But my use case is , I have to create a JsonLD out of it.

For that what I am currently doing is making something like:
Now My Case Class A for Json LD becomes:

```
 case class A(`contextA:a`:String, `contextA:b`:String, `contextA:c`:C,`contextA:d`:D,`@context`:ContextA)
```

Similarly:

```
case class C(`contextC:e`:String,`contextC:f`:String,`@context`:ContextC)
case class D(`contextD:g`:String,`contextD:h`:String,`@context`:ContextD)

case class ContextA(contextA:String="www.a.com")
case class ContextD(contextD:String="www.d.com")
case class ContextC(contextC:String="www.c.com")
```

**My Questions:**

1.Is this approach correct ? If not then whats the alternative ?

2.Is there any library in Scala or Java that can make my life easy and do this conversion automatically, because my case class has over 30 variables and is 5 times nested. Hence doing it manually is taking a lot of time !

**P.S.** : My main goal is to convert a simple Case class into Json LD format !

Comment: Thinking we could use `circe` custom codecs : https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think this project can help https://github.com/google/schemaorg-java if you need to generate Json+ld from and to Java objects described in http://schema.org context.

For more general task and usage of multiple contexts - RDF/JSON+ld Scala library https://github.com/banana-rdf/banana-rdf can help, but this is a more low-level approach. And probably won't help with your task.

It would be nice to have something like context -> scala classes generator. But didn't find such projects so far.